# Существует ли название такого типа классов-объектов?

Tags: php, ооп, терминология

Имеется например процедура/метод/функция которая достает данные из какой то таблицы в базе данных. Допустим она выбирает все поля и возвращает список объектов с магическими свойствами, имена которых совпадают с именами полей таблицы.

В связи с тем, что мы не видим эти свойства через intellisense нашей IDE в которой работаем при написании клиентского кода, мы можем ошибится в названии свойства и программа будет работать неправильно но при этом не выдаст ошибку. Существует такая практика, создавать классы для хранения таких объектов с нормальными не магическими свойствами и записывать информацию из базы при чтении в объекты. Ну и собственно далее можно писать программу используя intellisense и быть уверенным в отсутствии ошибок.

Вопрос, есть ли название в терминологии ООП или какой то другой, у таких классов/объектов ?

Comment: Например, [DTO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO) - объект без методов, просто описание структуры

Comment: Спасибо, думаю, что это вполне можно оформить в виде ответа, вы мне помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, [DTO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO) - класс без методов, просто описание структуры.

DTO удобно использовать совместно с [PDOStatement::fetchObject](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) / [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php)(с параметром PDO::FETCH_CLASS)

Answer (score 0):

А чем вам phpDoc не подходит?

```
/**
 * @method $this instance($name)
 */
class Result {

}

/**
 * @property Result $test
 */
class Magic {

}

$magic = new Magic();
$magic->test->instance('Hello')->instance('phpDoc');
```

---

**Обновиление**

```
//Класс описанный где-то в недрах vendors
class Magic {

}

#region Documentation

/**
 * Наш результат для примера
 * 
 * @property int $x координата по оси Х
 * @method instance($name)
 */
interface IResult {

}

/**
 * Магический класс, попробуйте его
 * 
 * @property IResult $test
 */
interface IMagic {

}

#endregion

/**@var IMagic $magic */
$magic = new Magic();
$magic->test->instance('Hello');
$magic->test->x;
```

Comment: Ну если вы возьмете и сможете убедить производителя фреймворка следовать вашим методам, то может и подойдет. Вопрос был общим, как именно называются такие классы а не как решить эту задачу подругому.

Comment: Обновил код. 

Так в этом и прелесть же phpDoc, что вы не зависите от производителя фреймворка. Можете описывать свои компоненты например. Да и если вы еще не перешли на PHP7, то описание типа данных очень даже помогают.

Я обычно документацию делаю через интерфейсы.

Comment: а я обычно пишу программы которые пишут другие программы.